# Find ordered non multiples of a given $~n~$

Tags: functions

Is there a function of any type and/or difficulty (Better non recursive) which returns ordered non multiples of a given $~n~$?

For $~n = 4~$ the output would be:

```
╔═══╦════╦
║ x ║ y  ║
╠═══╬════╬
║ 1 ║ 1  ║
║ 2 ║ 2  ║
║ 3 ║ 3  ║
║ 4 ║ 5  ║
║ 5 ║ 6  ║
║ 6 ║ 7  ║
║ 7 ║ 9  ║
║ 8 ║ 10 ║
║...║ .. ║
╚═══╩════╩
```

For "*ordered non multiples of a given $~n~$*" I mean all numbers which is not divisible by $~n~$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ordered non multiples of a given n

Comment: See the example, if n = 4 it should returns any number which is not divisible by 4, ordered

Comment: then I think I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y=\left\lfloor\frac{nx-1}{n-1}\right\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor$ denotes the integer part of $\alpha$ (i.e. the largest integer that is $\le\alpha$).

Comment: For $n = 4$ and $x = 7$ I would have $8$, which is a multiple of 4. Is that correct?

Comment: @ALFA: Whoops! I think I have it right now.

Comment: @TonyK That's it I think

Answer (score 1):

The function that you are looking for involves the floor function.

For you example of $n=4$ you function is $$f(k)= k + [\frac {k-1}{3}]$$

In general your function is $$f(k)= k + [\frac {k-1}{n-1}]$$

Comment: Thank you, but for $n = 4$ and $k = 7$ I would have $f(k) = 8$ which is a multiple of $4$, is that correct? Same for $k = 10$, I would have $f(k) = 12$

Comment: I already thought of this, I was on my way to writing it when I realised it doesn't work

Comment: $f(k)=k+\lfloor\frac{k-1}{n-1}\rfloor$

Comment: I edited my answer based on the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if I understand it correctly you may define recursively
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f(1)&=&1\\ 
f(n) & = &\mbox{min}\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m\not\in f(\{1,\ldots,n\})\mbox{ and }
m\not\in n\mathbb{N}
\} \end{array}
$$

where, $n\mathbb{N}=\{
mn:m\in\mathbb{N}
\}$ and the min does exist because the set is non-empty so the well-ordering principle applies

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is surely correct, but is there any way not to make it recursive? I need to implement it into some coding and It would be better an iterative function, or maybe a polynomial function if it is possible (even better). I will correct my "any kind or any difficulty" inside the question

Comment: I'll think about it. It looks like there should be one.